# Array of calendar month names or abbreviations

Tags: julia

In base R, we have easy access to an array containing the calendar month names, `month.names`, and to an array containing the calendar month abbreviations, `month.abb`:

```r
> month.name
# [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June" 
# [7] "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"

> month.abb
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

Similarly, in Python there are two array-like objects in the standard library `calendar` module:

```py
>>> from calendar import month_name, month_abbr
>>> list(month_name)
# ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
>>> list(month_abbr)
# ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Does Julia have a similar array of month names in the standard library `Dates` module, or perhaps a third-party package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@hckr has provided a nice answer about where these things are *currently* stored internally. However, `LOCALES` is not exported by `Dates`, and explicitly using non-exported objects from modules is something we should try to avoid. In this case, you could retrieve the month names using the (exported) function `monthname`:

```
julia> monthname.(1:12)
12-element Array{String,1}:
 "January"  
 "February" 
 "March"    
 "April"    
 "May"      
 "June"     
 "July"     
 "August"   
 "September"
 "October"  
 "November" 
 "December"
```

Comment: You forgot the cardinal rule: "Never use `collect`" ;) `monthname.(1:12)`.

Comment: I did not really know that there was a `monthname` method that takes an integer as month number when I wrote my answer. This is interestingly not yet documented. I have edited my answer to point to your correct answer.

Comment: I agree that the integer methods for `monthname`, `monthabbr`, `dayname`, and `dayabbr` should be documented.

Comment: I opened an issue in the julia github repo: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31761

Comment: @DNF Argh! Old, bad, MatLab habits :-)  Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See @Colin T Bowers' correct answer. You should use `monthname`, `monthabbr`, `dayname`, `dayabbr` functions to retrieve these names and abbreviations, e.g. `dayabbr.(1:7)` or `dayabbr(2)`. These functions can also take a `locale` argument to provide names/abbreviations in other languages/locales. My answer has become about where *currently* things are stored internally.

It has. They are stored in a `Dict` for available locales (only English, by default, though you can add others). You can access them with, for example `Dates.LOCALES["english"]`. This will give you a `struct` in the following form.

```
struct DateLocale
    months::Vector{String}
    months_abbr::Vector{String}
    days_of_week::Vector{String}
    days_of_week_abbr::Vector{String}
    month_value::Dict{String, Int}
    month_abbr_value::Dict{String, Int}
    day_of_week_value::Dict{String, Int}
    day_of_week_abbr_value::Dict{String, Int}
end
```

So, `Dates.LOCALES["english"].months_abbr` will give you the abbreviations of months in English as an array of strings. You can also get days of the week and their abbreviations. You can also add other locales to this dict using `DateLocale` constructors.

The information in `Dates.LOCALES['localename']` is also used when parsing dates in `localename` locale.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/index.html#Query-Functions-1